# Why Google is not making more colors for icons?

Tags: android, colors, icons, material-design

Good afternoon,

I do not understand why Google is only making white and black material design icons ?

[image]

Why not blue, red, green, **customised** ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always add tint to the imageview to get desired color icon !!

Comment: Mainly because these can be colored programmatically and otherwise.

Comment: Only on API 23+, isn't it ?

Comment: you can also use http://bitdroid.de/Android-Material-Icon-Generator/ to generate icon easily

Answer (score 0):

You can tint any image by code when using the support libraries like this:

```
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED);
```

the above code tints the image red, for example.

Comment: What is the minimal API needed ?

Comment: it's part of `support-v4`, so from API level 4 [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#setTint(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int))

Comment: it's part of support-v4 since v22.1.0 - also see [Chris Banes Post](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) about it